# GraphClient.cs not found

Tags: nuget, neo4jclient

I recently installed the `Neo4jClient Nuget` package on my VB.NET project and when I attempt to create a new graph client (code below) I get a `"GraphClient.cs not found"` error.

Dim client As New GraphClient(New Uri("http://myGraphServer.myCompany.com:7474/db/data"))

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

That's just something visual studio says when an exception has been thrown and it's trying to take you to the code.

Typically this happens this early on when you don't have the neo4j server running, or you have the wrong address to connect to.

Are you doing a

```
client.Connect()
```

call afterwards?

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  It is a visual studio thing, I think, because I get this error when I attempt to step through a neo4jclient call but if I just let it run then it works.